# Is there a simply way to receive Webhooks, Push Notifications, or SMS in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, webhooks

So I've developed an app that needs data from the website TradingView. Currently, I have alerts set on TradingView to send an email to my Gmail account, which my app regularly polls looking for emails with a specific subject line, then parses the necessary data from them. Obviously, this induces some lag between the TV alert and when my app receives the data.

TradingView ALSO has the ability to send a Webhook, Push Notification, or SMS alert with any desired syntax data. I was wondering if there would be a simple solution to receive Webhook, Push Notification, or SMS data on my Windows Forms app and bypass the email step.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebHooks are URLs that are used to call back to when state changes or new information is available. You could set up your WinForms app to respond to a webhook, but your WinForms application *would have to have an [HTTP server running](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)*, and your webhook URI would need to point at your PC.

So, if your IP address is `1.2.3.4` and your webserver is running on port 8090, your URL may look like this: `http://1.2.3.4:8090/api/myWebHook`

Make sure your network exposes port 8090 for IP address `1.2.3.4`

This is a very generic response, i am sure there are more hoops to jump through than just these steps.